# Понять механизм алгоритма сортировки вставкой и удаления дубликатов О(N)

Tags: java, алгоритм

**Задача**: написать алгоритм сортировки вставкой и добавить функцию удаления дубликатов в `O(N)`.

Самому додуматься получилось только до

```
insertionSort();

for (int i = 0; i < nElems; i++)
    while (a[i] == a[i + 1]) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < nElems; j++)
            a[j] = a[j + 1];
        nElems--;
    }
```

Но это уже `O(N²)`. В сети нашел вот такой способ, работает корректно, но в одном месте не понимаю, как.

```
insertionSort();

int total = nElems;
int shiftAmount = 0;
long currNum = 0;
for (int index = 0; index < total; index++) {
    if (a[index] == currNum) {
        shiftAmount++;
        nElems--;
    } else {
        currNum = a[index];
        a[index - shiftAmount] = a[index];
    }
}
```

**ВОПРОС**: допустим, тестируемый массив состоит из  таких данных: { 55, 55, 55, 44, 44, 11 }.
На втором шаге, когда `index` = 1 и `currNum` = 55, увеличивается `shiftAmount`, а `nElems--` должен (по идее) отсечь крайний элемент массива, как так получается что 11 остается на месте, а удаляется то что нужно (ведь 11 мы только что "потеряли", и массив превратился в { 55, 55, 55, 44, 44 })?

Comment: Цикл идет до `total`. Значение `nElems` никого не интересует. Ну и удаление должно производиться в отсортированном массиве

Answer (score 0):

Как я вижу, переменная `nElems` совершенно не используется во время программы. Это просто переменная, с помощью которой мы можем узнать уже после выполнения алгоритма количество уникальных элементов в массиве.

Если переписать код, убрав эту строчку совершенно ничего измениться. Программа будет также идти до самого конца.

```
total = nEelems;
for (int index = 0; index < total; index++) {
// .........................^
}
```

Переменная `total` просто скопировала значение `nElems`. То есть при изменении одной из них, другая не зависит от нее и не меняется. Таким образом алгоритм проходит полностью от начала до конца массива, не теряя ни одного элемента.